# What is the Python 3 equivalent of "python -m SimpleHTTPServer"

Tags: python, python-3.x, httpserver, simplehttpserver

What is the Python 3 equivalent of `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`?

Comment: python -m http.server 8000 , it will start the server on port 8000

Answer (score 2290, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html):

> The `SimpleHTTPServer` module has been merged into `http.server` in Python 3.0. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to 3.0.

So, your command is `python -m http.server`, or depending on your installation, it can be:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

Comment: In Python 3.3, the replacement for `python -m CGIHTTPServer` is `python3 -m http.server --cgi`.

Comment: Can you bind a different IP/Port with that command? How would I do that?

Comment: Sure, just tack it on the end of the command line. Read `python3 -m http.server --help` for all the args & options.

Comment: `python -m http.server` worked for me. I had to remove the `3`

Comment: @nueverest It depends on how your Python installation is 'named'. Usually Python2 is available as `python` and Python3 as `python3` but some prefer to install Python3 simply as `python`.

Comment: AFAIK, on Windows, it'll install as just `python` by default. But, the question is for `python3` :)

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `python -m http.server --bind 192.168.1.14 8000
>>> Serving HTTP on 192.168.1.14 port 8000 ... `

Comment: python3 is now named 'python' for homebrew-managed installs on OSX.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai more examples at the end of this section: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Comment: is it possible to call this in a py2x and py3x compatible way? I tried using the six library but it doesnt seem to work with: 'python -m six.moves.SimpleHTTPServer'

Comment: just installed python 3.7.1 on windows, neither `python` nor `python3` worked, just `py` worked!

Comment: @ParamvirSinghKarwal `py` is a wrapper on windows because Linux has a feature where if a script is marked executable and starts with a "shebang" (as in `#! /bin/python3`) executing it as a command (as in `./yourscript.py`) will run it with that program so you can chose which version to run your script under, unless someone manually does `python2 yourscript.py`. Windows uses just the files extension to decide which program to use so `py` is set to open .py files and looks for a shebang and then executes it under the correct python version.

Comment: And on Arch I have `python` (Python 3), `python2`, `python2.7`, `python3`, and `python3.7`. If a had 2.6 for example, I'd also have a `python2.6`.

Comment: another big fan of the " . " where people don't want one for copy & paste reasons. Must have been put there on purpose. <--- HERE a dot / full stop does belong, since there is no bash code involved, you see.

Comment: @dotbit: That was an unfortunate result of an edit which turned an inline code example (like the `python -m http.server`) into a paragraph that had only code in it – but left the trailing comma. I've now turned it into a real code block.
Please feel free to edit (or suggest edits) yourself when you see a mistake. Or just alert others if you see something that can be improved. There's no need for negativity :)

Comment: @PetrViktorin what is the default `--bind` if I don't specify it? I looked into the docs but I cannot find it.

Comment: @Kuzeko, the default is to listen on all interfaces (`''`).

Answer (score 370):

The equivalent is:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

Comment: And `python3 -m http.server 8080` if You need to bind to a port. Read more at the end of the section: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Comment: By default, it will bind to port 8000. See `python3 -m http.server --help` for details.

Answer (score 163):

Using 2to3 utility.

```
$ cat try.py
import SimpleHTTPServer

$ 2to3 try.py
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: buffer
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: idioms
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: set_literal
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma
RefactoringTool: Refactored try.py
--- try.py  (original)
+++ try.py  (refactored)
@@ -1 +1 @@
-import SimpleHTTPServer
+import http.server
RefactoringTool: Files that need to be modified:
RefactoringTool: try.py
```

Like many *nix utils, `2to3` accepts `stdin` if the argument passed is `-`. Therefore, you can test without creating any files like so:

```
$ 2to3 - <<< "import SimpleHTTPServer"
```

Answer (score 123):

In addition to Petr's answer, if you want to bind to a specific interface instead of all the interfaces you can use `-b` or `--bind` flag.

```
python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1
```

The above snippet should do the trick. 8000 is the port number. 80 is used as the standard port for HTTP communications.

Comment: python -m http.server 8081 --bind 127.0.0.1 If your 8000 is being used by another program.

Comment: If you are not in a virtual environment where you are running Python3 , please use python3 -m http.server 8081 --bind 127.0.0.1, otherwise you will get an error that /usr/bin/python: No module named http

Answer (score 42):

As everyone has mentioned [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server) module is equivalent to `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.

But as a warning from https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server

> **Warning**: `http.server` is not recommended for production. It only implements basic security checks.

## Usage

http.server can also be invoked directly using the `-m` switch of the interpreter.

```
python -m http.server
```

The above command will run a server by default on port number `8000`. You can also give the port number explicitly while running the server

```
python -m http.server 9000
```

The above command will run an HTTP server on port 9000 instead of 8000.

> By default, server binds itself to all interfaces. The option
> -b/--bind specifies a specific address to which it should bind. Both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses are supported. For example, the following
> command causes the server to bind to localhost only:

```
python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1
```

or

```
python -m http.server 8000 -b 127.0.0.1
```

Python 3.8 version also supports IPv6 in the bind argument.

### Directory Binding

By default, server uses the current directory. The option `-d/--directory` specifies a directory to which it should serve the files. For example, the following command uses a specific directory:

```
python -m http.server --directory /tmp/
```

Directory binding is introduced in python 3.7

Comment: Everyone mentions "Warning: http.server is not recommended for production. It only implements basic security checks." but do you have any suggestions for easy to use file servers as alternatives. I have a docker app and I would like to run something like this server in a separate container behind nginx. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

In one of my projects I run tests against Python 2 and 3. For that I wrote a small script which starts a local server independently:

```
$ python -m $(python -c 'import sys; print("http.server" if sys.version_info[:2] > (2,7) else "SimpleHTTPServer")')
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

As an alias:

```
$ alias serve="python -m $(python -c 'import sys; print("http.server" if sys.version_info[:2] > (2,7) else "SimpleHTTPServer")')"
$ serve
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Please note that I control my Python version via [conda environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html), because of that I can use `python` instead of `python3` for using Python 3.

Answer (score 11):

Just wanted to add what worked for me:
`python3 -m http.server 8000` (you can use any port number here except the ones which are currently in use)