# D3 Bar Graph example not working locally

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, local

I am very new to D3, and wanted to see how an example would work locally. I copied and pasted the bar graph code to a local file called index.html, and also copied over the data.tsv. For some reason, absolutely nothing is showing up when I open the file on a browser! I tried changing the script src to "d3/d3.v3.min.js" because that is the folder the d3 I downloaded is in. However, this does not work either. For every example I have tried I have yet to successfully view a D3 example. Help would be appreciated!

The index.html code is as follows:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
 display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
   .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(x)
   .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
 x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

});

function type(d) {
d.frequency = +d.frequency;
 return d;
}

</script>
```

and the data.tsv is in the following format:
letter  frequency
A   .08167
B   .01492
C   .02780
D   .04253
E   .12702
F   .02288
G   .02022
H   .06094
I   .06973

Comment: have you looked at the console, and if you have what does it say?

Answer (score 19):

The `d3.tsv` method makes an AJAX request for data. On most browsers, this won't work locally due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), which generally prohibits AJAX requests to `file:///` urls.

To get an example that uses AJAX running locally, you'll need a local webserver. If you have Python, running

```
> python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

from the command line in the directory with your files will do it.

and if you are using python **3**

```
> python -m http.server 9000
```

If you prefer node.js, try [http-server](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Would I have to do the same thing for a csv datafile?

Comment: Yup. `d3.csv` and `d3.json` are also making AJAX requests, so the same rules apply. You can use a local webserver, or you can inline it - those are basically the only options.

Comment: Also, from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943751/what-is-the-python3-equivalent-of-python-m-simplehttpserver), use `python -m http.server` if you are from the future and using Python 3.

Comment: After you run python server as suggested by @PrashantKumar, you need to open your html file like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.html`. It will not work if you open the html file from local disk directly.

Comment: So, when I run ng serve, it doesn't use the same port as wehn I run http-server. I get the error, "Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8080/master_grades_lecture.csv: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access." Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, and I was myself suggested by Lars Kotthoff when trying to work with .tsv/.csv files, you can work directly for this purpose on:

#### http://plnkr.co/

This enables you to work with all the .json / .tsv / .csv files you like, and share them with people for collaboration. You can do this anonymously or not, what matters is that you don't lose the then-generated HTTP address of your plunker.

One thing to pay attention to: you cannot upload directly the files in the way you would do on an FTP server, but you should instead:

1. Click on "new file"
2. Type the name of your .csv / .tsv / .json
   file as referred to in your code (including the extension)
3. Copy
   and paste the *code* contained in this file as is.
4. Don't forget
   to update the names of your .css / .js if required so the match with
   that of your  index.html

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, you're most likely encountering a CORS issue with the XHR in the d3 library for an external resource to parse the JSON data.

However, here is another solution: use JSONP and Express/Node.js in conjunction with a jQuery function to initiate a client-side request for JSON, instead of using the original wrapper for d3 functions.

Had to remove the original d3.json wrapper and populate the adjacency diagrams with data from the request. Begin by cloning or downloading [jsonp-d3-experiment](https://github.com/jchristianhall/jsonp-d3-experiment) and start the server using `node server.js`. Of course you need to have Node.js installed globally, beginning with Node Packaged Modules (npm). Copy your program into a subdirectory.

Put your JSON data in the jsonp-d3-experiment directory and modify `server.js` to route the request to your data:

```
// Return data from callback
server.get('/example', function(req, res)
{
  // Read the JSON data and send to JSONP response
  readJSON('example.json', function (e, json)
  {
    if (e) { throw e; }
    res.jsonp(json);
  });
});
```

Below is the code I modified for a co-occurrence matrix. I moved the entire script into `$.getJSON` and removed the `d3.json` function altogether.

```
<script>
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/example?callback=?", function(result){

      miserables = result;

      var margin = {
          top: 80,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 10,
          left: 80
        },
        width = 720,
        height = 720;

      var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, width]),
        z = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 4]).clamp(true),
        c = d3.scale.category10().domain(d3.range(10));

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


        var matrix = [],
          nodes = miserables.nodes,
          n = nodes.length;

        // Compute index per node.
        nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
          node.index = i;
          node.count = 0;
          matrix[i] = d3.range(n).map(function(j) {
            return {
              x: j,
              y: i,
              z: 0
            };
          });
        });

        // Convert links to matrix; count character occurrences.
        miserables.links.forEach(function(link) {
          matrix[link.source][link.target].z += link.value;
          matrix[link.target][link.source].z += link.value;
          matrix[link.source][link.source].z += link.value;
          matrix[link.target][link.target].z += link.value;
          nodes[link.source].count += link.value;
          nodes[link.target].count += link.value;
        });

        // Precompute the orders.
        var orders = {
          name: d3.range(n).sort(function(a, b) {
            return d3.ascending(nodes[a].name, nodes[b].name);
          }),
          count: d3.range(n).sort(function(a, b) {
            return nodes[b].count - nodes[a].count;
          }),
          group: d3.range(n).sort(function(a, b) {
            return nodes[b].group - nodes[a].group;
          })
        };

        // The default sort order.
        x.domain(orders.name);

        svg.append("rect")
          .attr("class", "background")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);

        var row = svg.selectAll(".row")
          .data(matrix)
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "row")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            return "translate(0," + x(i) + ")";
          })
          .each(row);

        row.append("line")
          .attr("x2", width);

        row.append("text")
          .attr("x", -6)
          .attr("y", x.rangeBand() / 2)
          .attr("dy", ".32em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "end")
          .text(function(d, i) {
            return nodes[i].name;
          });

        var column = svg.selectAll(".column")
          .data(matrix)
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "column")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            return "translate(" + x(i) + ")rotate(-90)";
          });

        column.append("line")
          .attr("x1", -width);

        column.append("text")
          .attr("x", 6)
          .attr("y", x.rangeBand() / 2)
          .attr("dy", ".32em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "start")
          .text(function(d, i) {
            return nodes[i].name;
          });

        function row(row) {
          var cell = d3.select(this).selectAll(".cell")
            .data(row.filter(function(d) {
              return d.z;
            }))
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "cell")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
              return x(d.x);
            })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("height", x.rangeBand())
            .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
              return z(d.z);
            })
            .style("fill", function(d) {
              return nodes[d.x].group == nodes[d.y].group ? c(nodes[d.x].group) : null;
            })
            .on("mouseover", mouseover)
            .on("mouseout", mouseout);
        }

        function mouseover(p) {
          d3.selectAll(".row text").classed("active", function(d, i) {
            return i == p.y;
          });
          d3.selectAll(".column text").classed("active", function(d, i) {
            return i == p.x;
          });
        }

        function mouseout() {
          d3.selectAll("text").classed("active", false);
        }

        d3.select("#order").on("change", function() {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          order(this.value);
        });

        function order(value) {
          x.domain(orders[value]);

          var t = svg.transition().duration(2500);

          t.selectAll(".row")
            .delay(function(d, i) {
              return x(i) * 4;
            })
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(0," + x(i) + ")";
            })
            .selectAll(".cell")
            .delay(function(d) {
              return x(d.x) * 4;
            })
            .attr("x", function(d) {
              return x(d.x);
            });

          t.selectAll(".column")
            .delay(function(d, i) {
              return x(i) * 4;
            })
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(" + x(i) + ")rotate(-90)";
            });
        }

        var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          order("group");
          d3.select("#order").property("selectedIndex", 2).node().focus();
        }, 5000);
      });
</script>
```

Notice that now the JSON data is in `result`, so the easiest thing to do was to assign it to `miserables`.

Note: jQuery is required for this solution.

Now you should be able to locally open and render all your d3 visualizations without hosting them on a server--simply open them in your browser straight from your local filesystem.

HTH!