# Display Pie chart, Grouped and Stacked bar chart in one page

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I want to display two charts in one page.The Pie chart gets displayed but the Grouped and Stacked bar chart is not displaying . I tried to change the Id name in  but no luck :( .  Will appreciate if anyone helps me with the code correction .

/* Display Matrix Chart ,Pie chart, Grouped and Stacked bar chart in one page */

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">

    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery1)}"/>    
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.D3)}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.nvD3)}"/> 

  <div id="body"  height="50%" width="100px" ></div>  // Id for Pie chart
  <div id="body1" height="30%" width="90px"></div>  // Id for Stacked and Grouped bar chart

<script>

// Matrix Chart starts here 
  var drawChart = function(divId,matrixReportId) {

        $.ajax('/services/data/v29.0/analytics/reports/'+matrixReportId,
            {
                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {!$Api.Session_ID}');
                },

                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);

                 var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();
                    var chartData = [];

                    document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = '';

                    $.each(response.groupingsDown.groupings, function(di, de) {
                        var values = [];
                        chartData.push({"key":de.label, "values": values});
                        $.each(response.groupingsAcross.groupings, function(ai, ae) {
                            values.push({"x": ae.label, "y": response.factMap[de.key+"!"+ae.key].aggregates[0].value});
                        });
                    });
                    d3.select('#'+divId).datum(chartData).transition().duration(100).call(chart);
                    window.setTimeout(function(){ 
                        drawChart(divId,matrixReportId);
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
        );
 };
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
   drawChart('chart','00O90000005SSHv');
 });

 //  Pie Chart Starts here

   var width =250 ,
    height = 450,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var data = [{"age":"<5","population":2704659},{"age":"14-17","population":2159981},
        {"age":"14-17","population":2159981},{"age":"18-24","population":3853788},
        {"age":"25-44","population":14106543},{"age":"45-64","population":8819342},
        {"age":">65","population":612463}];

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

     var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - 10).innerRadius(0);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

    var svg = d3.select("#body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


      var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
          .data(pie(data))
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "arc");

      g.append("path")
          .attr("d", arc)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });

      g.append("text")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });


 //  Grouped and Stacked Bar Chart starts here

     var n = 2, // number of layers
        m = 10, // number of samples per layer
        stack = d3.layout.stack(),
        layers = stack(d3.range(n).map(function() { return bumpLayer(m, .1); })),
        yGroupMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y; }); }),
        yStackMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; }); });

     var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 10},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

     var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.range(m))
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .08);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, yStackMax])
        .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, n - 1])
        .range(["#aad", "#556"]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .tickSize(0)
        .tickPadding(6)
        .orient("bottom");

    var svg = d3.select("#body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
        .data(layers)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "layer")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

    var rect = layer.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d) { return d; })
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .attr("y", height)
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("height", 0);

    rect.transition()
        .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); });

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    d3.selectAll("input").on("change", change);

    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      d3.select("input[value=\"grouped\"]").property("checked", true).each(change);
    }, 2000);

    function change() {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      if (this.value === "grouped") transitionGrouped();
      else transitionStacked();
    }

    function transitionGrouped() {
      y.domain([0, yGroupMax]);

      rect.transition()
          .duration(500)
          .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
          .attr("x", function(d, i, j) { return x(d.x) + x.rangeBand() / n * j; })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand() / n)
        .transition()
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); });
    }

    function transitionStacked() {
      y.domain([0, yStackMax]);

      rect.transition()
          .duration(500)
          .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
        .transition()
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand());
    }

    // Inspired by Lee Byron's test data generator.
    function bumpLayer(n, o) {

      function bump(a) {
        var x = 1/(.1 + Math.random()),
            y = 2*Math.random()-.5,
            z = 10/(.1 + Math.random());
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          var w = (i/n- y) * z;
          a[i] += x * Math.exp(-w * w);
        }
      }

      var a=[],i;
      for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i] = o + o * Math.random();
      for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) bump(a);
      return a.map(function(d, i) { return {x: i, y: Math.max(0, d)}; });
    }
    </script>
 <svg id="chart" height="50%" width="500px" ></svg>  // Id for Matrix chart
</apex:page>
Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

first, as we discussed here ([d3 Donut chart does not render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504337/d3-donut-chart-does-not-render)), you should position your

```
 <div id="body1" height="30%" width="90px"></div>
```

above the script.

second, you are missing the # in your second svg-declaration to correctly select the div by its id, it has to be

```
 var svg = d3.select("#body1").append("svg")
```

you could also think about naming the second svg differently (eg svg2) so you don't override your first svg-variable (in case you want to do something with it later).

Comment: Herbert,this is useful . But , what i'm trying now is Stacked and bar chart in first row , then in second row - Pie chart and matrix chart . But to my surprise all of them are showing it in seperate rows/divs . Have edited my code . So what this diplays is- first is Pie chart,second is Stacked and Grouped bar and lastly Matrix chart.  Any pointer ?

Comment: hm, not sure if i understand you correctly, but it sounds a little like its an issue with positioning?  
if that is the case, could you arrange your divs accordingly? one way the positioning is usually done is by creating a container div and then putting the other divs with the corresponding id inside this conainer, using css to arrange them.  
also, in your code, as far as i can see you now select the same div twice, once for the pie-chart, once for the bar-chart (twice `#body` and not `#body1`).

Comment: Yes, its about positioning the charts. I tried adjusting it with divs but no luck so far.So 1st line the Staked and grouped chart on first line . 2nd line - two charts , one is Pie chart and second is Matrix chart . Tried with CSS but they are overlapping . Any recommandation with the code will be the best .Thanks

Comment: ok, i put it in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99nuL/ - maybe it helps to play a little with the css. i think you should use the divs without height/width, as the appended svgs are larger than the boundaries you defined. if at all, these values should match. the matrix-chart does not get drawn, but that is probably due to the ajax-request. hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry Herbert, was on leave. I'm so much thankful to you . This has really increased my knowledge . Its a bingo !

Comment: can you please help me in getting this answer -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683498/issue-with-data-for-bar-chart-in-graph .. ?