# Highcharts - making the values dynamic instead of static

Tags: javascript, dynamic, highcharts

Have created a graph which includes bar chart with plotted lines and pie chart in it.  I'm trying to fetch values dynamically for bar chart but it is not displaying .Have uploaded the picture where bar/column chart doesn't show up and line chart shows where values are declared..Kindly help.

```
      <!-- Vf page-->
      <apex:page controller="HighchartsController">


      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

     <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin:0 auto"></div>

        <script>
             $(function () {
             $('#container').highcharts({
             title: {
             text: 'Chart showing opportunities'
        },
        xAxis:{
                categories: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May']
            },
              labels: {
              items: [{
              html: 'Opportunities',
              style: {
                    left: '50px',
                    top: '18px',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                }
            }]
        },
        series: [ {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Indian Railways',
            data: "[{!nvs}]"   // values coming from controller and here i need to fetch it.
        },
         {
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'Monthly Sales', // Average
            data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33],   
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                fillColor: 'white'
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Total consumption',
            data: [ {
                name: 'Lost',
                y:23,

                sliced:true,
                selected:true,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // Opp's Lost color
              }, 
             {
                name: 'Won',
                 y:19,

                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2] // Opp's won color
              }],
               center: [100, 80],
               size: 100,
               showInLegend: false,
               dataLabels:
               {
                 enabled:true
               }
           }]
       });
   });
    </script>
    </apex:page>


       //Apex class



       public class HighchartsController
      {  
           // for bar chart
           // N for name , v for data
          public class Nv {
             public String n { get; private set; }        
             public integer v { get; private set; }
                Nv(String n,Integer v) {
                 this.n = n;
                 this.v = v;       
            }  
         }
      public Nv[] getnvs() {
        return new Nv[] {
            new Nv('Jan',5),
            new Nv('Feb',45),
            new Nv('Mar',35),
            new Nv('Apr',25) ,      
            new Nv('may',15)
          };
        }
      }


 Highly appreciate the help.
```

Comment: I really need help from the experts and the community.I'm stucked. Please help

Comment: Could you show what is generated on browser? Here: `data: "[{!nvs}]"`. Anyway, I would remove `"`, to make this JS object, not a string, so something like this: `data: [{!nvs}]`

Comment: I did try that but it is not working . Link to refer to image displayed in browser : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/43804/how-to-get-data-dynamically-instead-of-static-data   .. By your comment , there is a ray of hope for me now .Thanks

Comment: As I said - add to you question what is rendered in browser in place of that variable.

Comment: Here is what i'm getting --  data: "[[Nv:[n=Jan, v=5], Nv:[n=Feb, v=45], Nv:[n=Mar, v=35], Nv:[n=Apr, v=25], Nv:[n=may, v=15]]]"   // values coming from controller and here i need to fetch it. Hope this is what you are expecting..

Comment: And that's wrong. It's not JavaScript format, so it won't work. Try to use solution from post on `salesforce` and paste here output.

Comment: I did try using josn.serialize but still it did not work ..How can i bring values from the database is still a question for me on Highcharts..

Comment: But could you show what was in output..?