# Importing local files for d3 in Angular2 projects generated using the cli

Tags: angular, d3.js

I'm trying to load a local csv file (or json file) in an angular2 project. I've tried a few variations per other SO questions (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972460/d3-bar-graph-example-not-working-locally)) or github issues, including:

1.) Setting up a local server using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` (which serves to port 8000), and executing:

```
d3.csv("http://127.0.0.1:8000/master_grades_lecture.csv", function(error, data){
      console.log(data[0]);
    });
```

When I do this, I can't just navigate to localhost:8000 in my browser and see the webapp working on index.html, because I've been using the Angular cli to set up my project, and it seems that it can only render when I run `ng serve` (which runs on port 4200).

2.) When I try to load this using `ng serve` on port 4200, and I change the above code to,

```
d3.csv("master_grades_lecture.csv", function(error, data){
      console.log(data[0]);
    });
```

I get an Access-Control-Allow-Origin related error.

Finally, there are also some typing issues when I compile that don't seem to yield many helpful insights when I search for them:

> ERROR in src/app/grade-display/grade-display.component.ts(20,41):
>   error TS2345: Argument of type '(error: DSVRowString, data: number) =>
>   void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(rawRow: DSVRowString,
>   index: number, columns: string[]) => DSVRowAny'.   Type 'void' is not
>   assignable to type 'DSVRowAny'.

These may or may not be separate issues. I'll be happy to provide a reproducible example if people feel like it's needed, but my hope is that somebody has had to deal with this issue before and knows exactly what's going on here. Forgive the newness to this topic.

UPDATE a reproducible example can be found here:

```
git clone https://github.com/Atticus29/whatismygrade.git
cd whatismygrade
git checkout SO
//create a test csv file in the app directory called master_grades_lecture.csv
rm package-lock.json
npm install
ng serve
```

Navigate to localhost:4200/test in browser

Comment: Are you willing to accept an alternative method (that is not accessible)?

Comment: @RandyCasburn which part is not accessible? And possibly; it depends on how alternative...

Comment: My silly autocorrect change 'that' to 'this' - I meant my alternative method is not accessible. Sorry for confusion

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm interested to know what an inaccessible alternative would mean... :-)

Comment: Use drag n' drop to move the file into your browser.

Comment: Ah. Gotcha. For my ultimate use case, that won't be an option, unfortunately.

Comment: ok - well it looks like a path problem when using the Angular in memory deployment. Is your assets folder being copied when you run ng serve?

Comment: I use Angular's http to read the csv then hand it off to d3 - works ok. Am I missing something? Any reason why you cannot use angular to fetch the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I notice is your @types/d3 is the wrong version.
You have

```js
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "d3": "^4.13.0",
},
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "@types/d3": "5.0.0",
```

so need to run `npm install --save-dev @types/d3@4.13.0` which should take care of typescript errors.

I didn't try your python server, but after running `ng serve` this code will work

```js
d3.csv('http://localhost:4200/assets/master_grades_lecture.csv', function(error, data){
  console.log('data', data);
});
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Comment: on version 5 of d3 you I used a different syntax.  I used a promise.  `.then` like so `d3.csv("https://some-data.csv").then((data)=>{ console.log(data) })`