# How to run html file on localhost?

Tags: javascript, html, localhost, webcam, mirror

I have an HTML file and I run it on localhost. But, this file includes a mirror using a webcam. For example, how can I run [this HTML file](https://web.archive.org/web/20150826061821/http://myprojectguide.org/p/flash-videoio/test.html) on localhost? Webcam starts in this example when checking to live checkbox.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use `python -m http.server`. By default the local server will run on port 8000. If you would like to change this, simply add the port number `python -m http.server 1234`

If you are using python 2 (instead of 3), the equivalent command is `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Comment: I create HTTPServer. What will i do now?

Comment: OK. I am done. I transport my project to C:/Python27 and i run it on http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: So you run the python command "python -m SimpleHTTPServer"  and then navigate to http://localhost:8000/ in your browser and click the desired html file. Great solution!

Comment: The python 3 equivalent is `python3 -m http.server` You want to navigate to the directory that contains the files you wish to open locally, and then run that command. Then open up localhost:8000 if you are using the default port.

Answer (score 234):

You can run your file in [**http-server**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

1> Have **Node.js** installed in your system.

2> In CMD, run the command **npm install http-server -g**

3> Navigate to the specific path of your file folder in CMD and run the command **http-server**

4> Go to your browser and type **localhost:8080**. Your Application should run

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I was looking for! Easy to do and works ;)

Comment: Even faster for one-time run is `npx http-server` from the folder you want to share. To add CORS you can run `npx http-server --cors`.

Comment: Make sure to run the `cmd` as an administrator

Comment: @sax if you put that in an answer I would vote on it!

Answer (score 21):

If you are running Python3, you may want to instead try:

```
python -m http.server
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943751/what-is-the-python-3-equivalent-of-python-m-simplehttpserver).

Answer (score 18):

If you have [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) installed then from the folder you want to share you can simply run:

```
npx http-server
```

To add CORS you can run:

```
npx http-server --cors
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working on end is "npx http-server"

Answer (score 10):

### On macOS:

Open Terminal (or iTerm) install [Homebrew](https://www.brew.sh) then run `brew install live-server` and run live-server.

You also can install [Python 3](https://python.org) and run `python3 -m http.server PORT`.

### On Windows:

If you have VS Code installed open it and install extension liveserver, then click Go Live in the bottom right corner.

Alternatively you can install WSL2 and follow the macOS steps via apt (`sudo apt-get`).

### On Linux:

Open your favorite terminal emulator and follow the macOS steps via apt (`sudo apt-get`).

Comment: Your VSCode suggestion was perfect for me. I was already using VSCode and I just needed a way to host a demo site locally for me to play around. The Go Live extension is a perfect one-click solution

Answer (score 9):

- Install Node js - https://nodejs.org/en/
- go to folder where you have html file:

  - In CMD, run the command to install http server- `npm install http-server -g`
  - To load file in the browser run - `http-server`
- If you have specific html file. Run following command in CMD.- `http-server fileName`
- by default port is `8080`
- Go to your browser and type `localhost:8080`. Your Application should
  run there.
- If you want to run on different port: `http-server fileName -p 9000`

> Note : To run your .js file run: `node fileName.js`

Answer (score 5):

As Nora suggests, you can use the python simple server.
Navigate to the folder from which you want to serve your html page, then execute `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.
Now you can use your web-browser and navigate to http://localhost:8000/ where your page is being served.
If your page is named index.html then the server automatically loads that for you. If you want to access any other page, you'll need to browse to http://localhost:8000/{your page name}

Answer (score 3):

You can try installing one of the following localhost softwares:

1. xampp
2. wamp
3. ammps server
4. laragon

There are many more such softwares but the best among them are the ones mentioned above. they also allow domain names (for example: `example.com`)

Answer (score 2):

Another option if you have Node.js installed,

```
npx serve .
```

It will serve you a static site/single page application in the current directory.

[Reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)

Answer (score 1):

You can install Xampp and run apache serve and place your file to www folder and access your file at localhost/{file name}
or simply at localhost if your file is named index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use PHP to server the files in http

make sure you installed PHP, run the below command to verify

```
php --version
```

if PHP is not installed run below command to install it

```
sudo apt install php7.4-cli
```

Once after the installation go to the file path and execute the below command in the terminal

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 1):

just     `npx serve`   it's more compatible with esmodule