# How to add a GeoJSONLayer to a map from json file ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I created a point layer in ArcMap, then, using the Features to JSON tool, converted these points into a JSON file and ticked GeoJSON, trying to add it to the map:

```
let layer = new GeoJSONLayer({
url: "data/points.json"
});

let map = new Map({
basemap: "dark-gray"
});

map.add(layer);

let mapview = new MapView({
container: "map",
map: map
});
```

But nothing appears on the map, I tried to change the format to .geojson, the same way, if I change the url to a link from the documentation, then all the rules, dots appear, what am I doing wrong?
Maybe the problem is in the json file?
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YxKfhiQMD82W2EI1llsmQaVD3kWgnWP-

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? When you exported to json with the tool in Arcmap did you check the box to export as geojson? What spatial reference is the data in? In order to be added as a geojson layer it must be in WGS84

Comment: @BigGerman, WGS 1984 World Mercator?

Comment: No, just WGS 1984. WKID 4326. Re-project your data to that using the "Project" tool in ArcMap, then run the export to json again.

Comment: @BigGerman, nothing changed, layer is not displayed and errors in console.

Comment: So there are errors in the console? or not? Are you serving the page on localhost or just copying the file path into your browser? If going through file path you may get a CORS error when trying to load the json file.

Comment: @BigGerman, just copy the file path.

Comment: Okay try serving the file on localhost, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497334/how-to-run-html-file-on-localhost)

Comment: Also if you are getting errors can you update your post with those error messages?

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. I didn’t know that a local server is needed for this