# Cannot use import statement outside a module(Vanilla Javascript)

Tags: javascript

when i tried to import a class from one js file to another i got this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

when i added type="module" to my script tags i got this error

> Access to script at 'file link' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

any help on how to fix the error ?

Comment: You'll need to show how you are writing your `import` statement, and the relative folder structure between your js files.

Comment: Sounds like you're opening your HTML file directly in the browser... you can fix this error by serving your web files from an HTTP server running on localhost

Answer (score 1):

this was simply solved by adding type="module" to my script tags and serving my web files from an HTTP server running on localhost instead of opening the html file directly

> these answers were helpful :

[How to run html file on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497334/how-to-run-html-file-on-localhost/38497387)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have to include the `type="module"` attribute in your `script` tag.

Secondly, when using the import statement, don't leave out the file extension, in this case `.js`.
e.g: `import { sqrRoot } from "./math_function.js"`

Answer (score 0):

Just run your application by using your http server. Do not access it directly.

Comment: No more local development from file:/// ?.. Times, times...