# Use Web3 in Google AppScript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, solidity, libraries, web3js

How do you use Web3 in Google App Script? So far I managed to view the Web3 Library code in the console using this:

```
var Web3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/3.0.0-rc.5/web3.min.js").getContentText();
Logger.log(Web3)
```

However when I try to create a new object using `var web3 = new Web3({parameters})`, it gives a type error stating Web3 isn't a constructor. Also when I try to use `eval("var x = "+Web3)` it gives

> Reference Error: window is not defined.

Comment: Try putting this in the head: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/3.0.0-rc.5/web3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65802366/metamask-does-not-inject-window-ethereum-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-canno

Comment: Tl;Dr Google Apps Script runtime executes code on the server, so there aren't objects from web APIs like `window`, `document` etc.