# React app does not render when metamask is not installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, metamask, decentralized-applications

I get this error in the console whenever metamask is not installed in the browser.:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.ethereum is undefined
```

It's all just a black screen

Comment: This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65802366/metamask-does-not-inject-window-ethereum-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-canno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is to wrap anything that references `window.ethereum` with an if:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(window.ethereum) {
    window.ethereum.on('chainChanged', () => {
      window.location.reload();
    })
    window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', () => {
      window.location.reload();
    })

    // Your extra code here
  }
})
```