# Can't connect to Jekyll's localhost:4000 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, localhost, jekyll

I'm trying to set up Jekyll on my Windows 10 machine, but can't connect to the website (127.0.0.1:4000) that is created by `jekyll serve` (or `bundle exec jekyll serve`). I have followed all the steps in Julian Thilo's [Run Jekyll on Windows](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/) without any error messages. And when I run `jekyll serve` in PowerShell from my Jekyll website folder everything seems just fine:

```
Configuration file: C:/Users/fredr/dropbox/github/jekyll-website/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/fredr/dropbox/github/jekyll-website
       Destination: C:/Users/fredr/dropbox/github/jekyll-website/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
                    done in 0.457 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'C:/Users/fredr/dropbox/github/jekyll-website'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

But when I open http://127.0.0.1:4000 (or http://localhost:4000) in my browser, the connection fails.

When I run `netstat -an`, the port `4000` is listed as

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

I have previously managed to set up a localhost using IIS, but that website is stopped now.

[This Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1285) seems related, but doesn't contain enough information for me to figure out how the problem was solved. It only says to use the "Jekyll on windows package", but I can't find any information on that.

Comment: Have you tried `localhost:4000`?

Comment: @JoostS Many, many times :(

Answer (score 2):

Following in @Fredrik P's footsteps, I CD'd into the project's `_site` folder (this is where the home folder of the server should be) and ran a Python 3.x simple HTTP server:

```
D:\frida\frida-website\_site>python -m http.server 3999
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 3999 (http://0.0.0.0:3999/) ...
```

Now pointing my browser to `http://0.0.0.0:3999/` works like a charm.

If you need to use Python 2.x, the HTTP server command would be:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3999
```

For more information regarding `SimpleHTTPServer` (2.x) and `http.server` (3.x), see [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7943751/562242).

Answer (score 1):

Until some better solution pops up, I will just host the `_site` folder with IIS. Not as fancy pancy but works like a charm :)