# jekyll NOT converting site.url to http://localhost:4000 per the documentation

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

can anyone help me figure out why site.url does NOT change to `http://localhost:4000` per the [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/news/2016/10/06/jekyll-3-3-is-here/#3-siteurl-is-set-by-the-development-server)? It mirrors the url param in _config.yml. I have checked and jekyll.environment = development.

I have spun up a new Jekyll project on a different machine and the results are the same.

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been disabled in [version 4.2.0](https://jekyllrb.com/news/2020/12/14/jekyll-4-2-0-released/). What a waste of time this has been.

[Here's a workaround.](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8541#issuecomment-758790803)

Comment: I have edited my answer, and suggested a workaround;

Comment: Exactly: I just found the exact same workaround, explicitly referenced and detailed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That documentation does mention:

> It will *not* be set if you set `JEKYLL_ENV=production` and run `jekyll serve`.
>
> If `JEKYLL_ENV` is any value except `development` (its default value), Jekyll will not overwrite the value of URL in your config.
> And again, this only applies to serving, not to building.

So double-check your  `JEKYLL_ENV` value, and your command (`jekyll serve`)

The OP points out to [`jekyll/jekyll` PR 7253](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/7253) in [jekyll v4.2.0](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/history/#v4-2-0)

> Local tests show that the local preview server is based on `config["host"]` and `config["port"]` values..
> So even if `config["url"] == https://jekyllrb.com`, the site will be served at the default setting: `//127.0.0.1:4000`
>
> This simplifies users' workflow by not having to build the site again with `JEKYLL_ENV=production`
> (unless their templates are designed to render differently for the two ENV vars, which is a different story altogether)

This, however, is in the process of being reverted: [PR 8620](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/8620)

> The documentation on jekyllrb.org was not updated to reflect this change in behavior,
>
> That change did not affect cases where the local server URL was explicitly set via `bundle exec jekyll serve --host localhost --port 4000` to be `localhost:4000`, or when it was set to be any other combination of hosts or ports.
>
> That change only affected the default `jekyll serve`, which is the local development action recommended in the Jekyll docs.

So this could be a workaround in your case:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --host localhost --port 4000
```

Comment: I mentioned in my post that the `jekyll.environment` variable is set to `development`. I don't know how else to test this since the documentation does not specify what kind of variable `JEKYLL_ENV` is. Is it an environment variable? A site variable? Either way, I think it's set correctly.

Comment: @user16270045 Exactly: en environment variable. Type `env` on Linux or `set` on Windows, to check if that environment variable is set.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. I've set the variable and the results are the same. I'm sure it's' the correct variable, because I can see the results when I output `{{site.url}}`. I'm still getting the _config.yml settings and not `http://localhost:4000/`.

Comment: @user16270045 What OS and OS version are you using? What shell version? And are you typing `jekyll serve` in the same CMD/shell where you see the environment variable `JEKYLL_ENV` set to `development`? (What version of `jekyll` are you using?)

Comment: @user16270045 Does a python (3) serve works, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59392477/6309?

Comment: See my reply. The feature has been disabled in version 4.2.0. 

Thanks for the help.