# How can I make link to local index.html file work correctly on Mac?

Tags: macos, web, web-testing

I'm developing a simple website with pure static html pages on my Mac. Before pushing to the server, I of course want to view the local html files in a browser. However, annoyingly clicking relative links to directories, e.g. `foo/` does not open the corresponding `foo/index.html` within the browser. Instead, Mac's Finder app launches up to the `foo/` directory. This happens in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox, so I guess it is a Mac issue. Is there a setting that would control this?

Comment: what does your browser show if you type `http://localhost`

Comment: You'd have to have a webserver up and running, in order to configure it to disallow 'indexes' in a specific directory.

Comment: Going to `http://localhost` says `cannot connect`. I do not have a web server running.

Comment: You might find the discussion here about [running a simple http server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800143/ad-hoc-webserver-for-static-files-on-unix-macosx) useful.